# Can not stick nav to the top.. middle done with flex,and nav won't get to the top

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need help, this is my code. I've done what I need for the landing page, but can not make navigation bar stick to the top it is just hanging just above the middle of the screen.

Don't know what to do with flex, or is in this example flex the problem, or what?
I have tried position relative, absolute, flex start end, everything, I am pretty much exhausted from looking at this. Can not find the solution.

AND THIS IS THE Snipt View

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #99b525;
  line-height: 1.6;
}

#showcase {
  background-image: url('img/lap-top.jpeg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  opacity: 0.9;
  padding: 0 20px;
  text-shadow: -2px 3px 2px #666;
  text-align: center;
}

#showcase h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

#showcase p {
  font-size: 20px;
}

#showcase .header .button {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #777;
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: #a3bd3b;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.8s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.8s ease-out;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.8s ease-out;
  transition: background-color 0.8s ease-out;
}

#showcase .header .button:hover {
  background: #a3bd3b;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: none;
}

.header {
  border: 3px solid #7c9c28;
  border-radius: 50px 25px 50px 25px;
  padding: 25px;
  background: #232323ad;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}


/*---------------------------------------------------*/

nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: transparent;
}

nav ul {
  float: left;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px 4em;
}

nav ul li a {
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #222;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 24px 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<header id="showcase">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Welcome to the beach</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolar sit anet, amat der is tlen af serf nsajs jsiqo msnf kaiwks.</p>
    <a href="#" class="button">Read More</a>
  </div>
</header>
```

What to do to make this right?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your justify-content 'center' is causing the issue as it's attempting to push everything into the middle.

If you're insistent on using the flexbox method (and depending on where you want the rest of your webpage), you can alter this to flex-start (so that everything moves to the top of the page).

```
#showcase {
  background-image: url('img/lap-top.jpeg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center; /* change to flex-start */
  opacity: 0.9;
  padding: 0 20px;
  text-shadow: -2px 3px 2px #666;
  text-align: center;
}
```

However, assuming you want your content "Welcome to the beach" in the middle, my personal solution would be to add this to your nav style:

```
nav {
     position:fixed;
     top:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try removing #showcase height .
if you want sticky menu try

```
position:fixed;
```